# Error handling messages for restfull API serving SPA?

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, django-rest-framework, single-page-application

We are facing problems working with django rest framework when it comes to error handling. auto-generated errors are json objects that looks like

```
{"age": "this field must be an integer"}
```

Clients need something more user friendly like :

> age field must be an integer.

Any solution to handle this ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how and why your users see raw API errors?

Comment: we use notifications on front that looks like http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Bootstrap-Based-Toast-Notification-Plugin-toaster.jpg which is not really compatible with the way django rest framework works

Comment: Then I suppose it's easier to write small code for your toast notifications that converts DRF's errors into preferred format than to rewrite DRF error handling. But if you willing to do so: [docs for exceptions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)

Comment: show your model and views...

Answer (score 0):

you can make your own `error_codes.py` file and put your own readable error with your own error code for example like this....

```
HTTP_MY_ERROR = {"error_desc": "your own readable error",
                     "error_code": 99}
```

now you can send your function response as...

```
return Response(error_codes.HTTP_MY_ERROR, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: That was an example to explain the way I want error message to be displayed

Comment: i have changed the answer accordingly...have a look... @user2080105

Comment: I think it would be more DRY if I can do this in a higher level, There are a lot of built-in error messages. customizing them would be better than customizing errors for each field that would be painful